# PHP code for asynchronous file upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot find what is the right PHP code as to send to the server an image file...
Consider the following:

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="dragarea"></div>
      <input type="file" id="fileselect"  name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

and the JS code which is executed upon a click event on the file I have dropped inside the `dragarea`:

```
  var fd = new FormData($('#upload')[0]);
  $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"upload.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{fd1:fd}, 
        contentType: false,      
        cache: false,             
        processData:false,  
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        } 
   })
```

and my `upload.php`

```
$filename = $_FILES['fd1']['name'];  
echo json_encode( $filename);
```

***While fd is not empty, $filename is null. Why that?***

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line :

```
data:{fd1:fd},
```

With this :

```
data:fd,
```

So your file would be accessible with :

```
$filename = $_FILES['fileselect'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Make a `print_r` of $_FILES